# How can I compare two MySQL databases locally?

Tags: mysql, database, compare

Is there an easy way to compare two MySQL databases locally? My host will not allow remote connection to the database.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to compare? Are you looking for some kind of mysql clients? e.g sqlyog?

Comment: Hi. I am looking to compare two .sql files that are on my desktop.

Comment: Just check their size in bytes. If they are exactly the same size, they are probably the same file. I don't know what you are trying to accomplish, though, since your question is so vague.

Answer (score 0):

Recently released, [MySQL Utilities](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/mysql-utils-man-overview.html), where there is a utility for comparing databases [mysqldbcompare](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/mysqldbcompare.html).

**UPDATE**

Rather than compare two databases, you need to compare two text files. Get tools to compare files, depending on your operating system, there are many options.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I am not sure how to use this to compare two .sql files that I have stored on my desktop?